# Selected Border Around FlipView in Windows 8 App

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a flipview that takes up the full screen of the application.

Inside of that flip view I have controls such as an image, some textboxes and a couple of listviews.

When I am entering data in the textboxes and tab through them, the flipview gets a selected border around it.

I have tried setting isTabStop="False" and this does not solve the problem. I have tried setting the Margin="-3" which does alleviate the selected border showing, but then I am not able to reach the last item in the flipview when being used with touch.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can stop this cosmetic problem with my application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a solution to you, but it worked well for me. And I didn't experience any problems with touch and I can still reach all items in the FlipView (also ListViews). I simply created a copy of the FlipView style and set Margin to 0. See (excerpt) below:

```
<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0">
```